# What is the best practice to handle long external process in ASP.NET page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

An example will be something like: User clicks a button on a webpage I created with ASP.NET.
My app calls an API hosted on a third party server.  The user sees a spinning icon/Please wait message, while my app is waiting the third party server to return the results to me, which may take a minute.

The solution isn't limited to what version of .NET.

Comment: Is there objectively a *best* way?  I don't think so.  I think you've phrased your question in an unanswerable way.  Your question may perhaps be better phrased as something like, "How can I display a 'please wait' message during a long-running external API call?"

Answer (score -1):

In most cases, since you can't wait for code behind to finish (since the web page is stuck up on the server), and ONLY after ALL your code behind is done, can the page THEN travel back down to client side, be re-freshed, JavaScript starts running, and THEN the results are displayed client side. In effect code behind NEVER interacts directly with the user, but only with the web page and ONLY while the page has been posted up to the server, travels up to the server. Your code behind can then in this very short time, modify values on the page, and then the while page is sent back to the client.

So, what this means is you have to adopt ajax. That means you write JavaScript client side, and they can call a web service you setup on your web site. In such cases then, no post-back of the page has occurred, and there are "many" features of JavaScript that allow you to do this. (such as promise, await, etc.). So, most web service calls by nature are asynchronous (you don't know how long you have to wait). So, yes, this is quite much the best practice, and how this common type of issue is to be approached.

So, in effect you not use code behind on the web page for this, but create a web service (web method) for the given page, or a separate aspx page with your required web  service calls. Such pages do NOT have use of the controls on your current page, don't have use of ViewState, but can use session().

So, just google making web service calls in asp.net.

You can however also start a new process thread, and have it talk to that "other service". And then say drop in a timer (and even a up-date panel ). It could trigger every one second, and poll say a database (or session()) values to determine when done, and then update the web page, and then stop the timer.

So, the timer trick means you can often avoid writing a web service, and then having to wire up the ajax calls to web methods in JavaScript. (this is the correct way, but the timer + starting another process can work quite well also, and in most cases eliminates the need for a web service and ajax calls).

Comment: Using long running HTTP requests to solve this isn't ideal either. You tie up ports, you keep web server threads occupied that could be handling other requests, and you likely need to increase timeouts to accomodate these long running requests, thus making your site more vulnerable to a denial of service attack. So the proper solution is to implement a background worker, like [Stephen Cleary described here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72232650/1139830). Client submits initial request, that goes into a queue, and a success response is returned to a client immediately.

Comment: When that background process is finished, the user can be notified in whatever way is best, such as a push notification, SignalR call to the site, email notification etc. That keeps the whole process scalable, and avoids the pit falls of long running HTTP requests. Of course, this opinion based question shouldn't have been answered in the first place. Vote to close appropriately.

Comment: Yes, but setting up notifications - even allowing a browser to see/get and deal with a push notification means some frame work and some architecture (and client side js code) has to be adopted. It would have been really nice if a web standard for server side push notifications (without a bunch of complex client side script having to be adopted) would be nice. But, no such standard exists. Ah, the state-less nature of web, and how it a challenge for push notifications. As noted, signalR, or setting up JavaScript to subscribe to push events is the way to go - but it requires code client side.

Comment: I didn't say this wouldn't require client side code to accomplish. I said you shouldn't having long running HTTP requests, because there are many negative effects if you do that. Yes, some coding is involved, and that might potentially mean you need to pull in a framework to accomplish that. Those aren't really valid reasons not do do it though. The implications of long running HTTP requests are a far bigger problem.

Comment: No problem. My apologies if you read this as me suggesting YOU did not know this, or you were somehow suggesting that some framework is not required. I betting 100% you are very aware of this! I just wanted to be sure the poster knows that setting up a push notification will involve several moving parts - it not easy the first time around - especially for the new ones here.  So, you did not mislead here. This Mr. Obvious issue for us is not the same for new users - they need info that doing this is lots of extra moving parts and I wanted the poster to be well aware of this.